# The expression specified in the EVALUATE statement is not a valid table expression

Tags: ssas, dax, ssas-tabular

I'm working on a Tabular cube in Visual Studio. 
I have a DAX formula in the cube that works fine:

```
SUMX(FILTER(factFHA, factFHA[EventCd]="D"), [LoanCount])
```

When I run it in SSMS as:

```
evaluate(
    SUMX(FILTER(factFHA, factFHA[EventCd]="D"), [LoanCount])
)
```

it fails with following error:

> Query (1, 1) The expression specified in the EVALUATE statement is not a valid table expression.

I have 2 other formulas that both work fine:

```
evaluate(factFHA)

evaluate(filter('factFHA', [EventCd] = "D"))
```

I can't figure out what is wrong with the `SUMX` with `FILTER`

Please advise. Thank you.

Comment: This is DAX, not MDX.  Please don't tag it as MDX - thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[EVALUATE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg492201.aspx) function only works if you pass a table or an expression that returns a table, you are passing a [SUMX](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-co/library/ee634959.aspx) function which return a scalar value (Decimal).

The syntax to write queries using DAX, is as follows:

```
[DEFINE {  MEASURE <tableName>[<name>] = <expression> } -> Define a session (optional) measure
EVALUATE <table>  --> Generate a table using your measures or creating calculated columns
[ORDER BY {<expression> [{ASC | DESC}]}[, …] --> Order the returned table by a passed column or expression 
[START AT {<value>|<parameter>} [, …]]] --> This is an ORDER BY Sub-clause to define from which the query results will start.
```

Define your measure then use then use it inside the EVALUATE clause using a expression that evaluates to a table.

```
DEFINE
MEASURE factFHA[MyMeasure] =
    SUMX ( FILTER ( factFHA, factFHA[EventCd] = "D" ), [LoanCount] )
EVALUATE
( SUMMARIZE ( FILTER ( factFHA, factFHA[EventCd] = "D" ), factFHA[AnyColumnToGroup]
              , "Sum of MyMeasure", SUM ( factFHA[MyMeasure] ) ) )
```

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: This helped me. except that I need to have SUM for the last parameter in SUMMARIZE. I edit the answer. Thank you.

Comment: But is does not filter my data. it just ignores the FILTER section. Any Idea?

Comment: @FLICKER, I've updated the summarize expression, give it a try.

Comment: This works. However I don't know why you have the DEFINE section. Only the EVALUATE statement give me the result

Comment: @FLICKER, I used The DEFINE clause to show you the structure of query in DAX. But in this case it is doing nothing since we aren't using it in the EVALUATE clause. You can delete it if you want.

Comment: Great!. Thank you for your time.